# How to fix the alignment/position of a image label (for checkboxes/radio buttons)?

Tags: html, css, layout, radio-button

Code is taken from 2 different sources, I would append but I dont have 10 rep to post them.

[First attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/2svjfeLs/1/). Notice the horribly placed radio buttons.

[Second attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/xwussun1/4/). I donot know the source, it was a direct google result. Notice the difference between top and bottom padding/alignment.

I tried using `[li]` element but it didnt work.

Adding `img{display: block;}` to the CSS gives unexpected results. It "fills" the whole element with the image, and the left part of image is hidden behind the green part.

I am a self-professed CSS/HTML noob, I can understand some things and do simple things but placement/alignment is still a mystery for me.

I'd like to know how this code works. I am planning to add a green border for the "selected" "button" and change some minor visual stuff. I'd also like to know how to center the "tick" and to implement the "tick" mark locally/globally and not rely on `content:'\2714';`.

Help me understand what is happening here, and how I can fix this (and apply the knowledge in the future).

**EDIT :** Updated the 2nd attempt, it is looking quite good, imho. Only if the alignment was fixes.... *sigh*.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this will sound really silly...

i added :

```
img
{
  display:block;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 45px;
}
```

and edited the margins... its now working properly.

but i STILL dont understand just WHY there was that bad space at the bottom.

here's the new version : http://jsfiddle.net/xwussun1/5/

**EDIT : ** ALSO fixed the tick mark position by adding `line-height: 6;`.

Comment: The "bad" space at the bottom is due to the fact that by default, the image tag is inline, and after you changed it to a block element and now it will occupy the available space from it's inherited parent. http://webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you would want to achieve?
http://jsfiddle.net/xwussun1/7/

Not sure I understood correctly,but here we go:
I've centered the box this way

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -20px; (minus half the height of the element)
height: 40px;
```